# What does "stop hounding us for puns" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> A: No dog jokes today.
>   A: Come on - throw me a bone
>   B: Stop hounding us for puns
>   A: I am dog-tired of these
>   B: Not that it mutters
>   A: Time to paws and reflect on whether these are are funny or just drool
>   B: fu-kennel that was bad

What is the meaning of this idiom: "stop hounding us for puns"? I heard it from a coworker saying to another one. He did not say it in a serious tone.
I actually don't understand the whole story here.

Comment: This needs more context. What was the topic of discussion?

Comment: Let me guess: these were both guys? :) The "conversation of puns" is one of those inexplicable rituals that certain sub-populations of male homo sapiens engage in. If they start such a ritual, there's nothing to do other than to get out of earshot.

Comment: I've seen it just as often in mixed groups as in all-male groups.  The game is to say things that imply that you don't want to hear any more puns, while simultaneously making more puns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"stop hounding us"* would mean *"stop bothering us"* or *"stop coming after us (because you want something)"*.

"Hounds" are dogs that are used in hunting:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hound

Because they are for that purpose, they are not supposed to give up.  They keep going after the prey (even though the prey doesn't want them to).  So to "hound" is to follow or pester or bother someone about something.

A similar phrase would be "stop badgering us", since badgers are known for being very persistent in a fight, and do not give up easily.

> "stop hounding us for puns"

A pun is a kind of joke based on wordplay:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun

So we'd assume these people have made such jokes in the past.  Now that they have done so, everyone wants them to make more--when they want to be more serious or get work done.  They are asking to stop bothering them to make more of these jokes (apparently without actually being bothered).

Comment: Calling a pun a type of joke implies that the pun is supposed to be funny, which is manifestly untrue: no matter how clever the pun, the proper and expected reaction is a groan, not a laugh. ;)

Comment: @Martha You never know. When a pun's all groaned up, it might graduate to dry British humour. :P

Comment: @Lawrence: THWACK!

Comment: @Martha Now, that was a reaction most *improper and unexpected*. :) And with that, I'm bowing out before the mods suspend me below a hounding reply of HostileFork's. Enjoy your day!

Comment: Notice that all the statements are related to dogs: hound, mutt-ers, bone, paws, kennel, thus all dog-related puns.